# Serializing and deserializing of type T, derived from Dictionary<string, T>, using Json.NET

Tags: c#, dictionary, json.net

I have created a sample project. I am serializing the following types:

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true, ItemReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize)]
public class SampleTree : Dictionary<string, SampleTree>
{
    [JsonProperty(ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize)]
    public SampleClass Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(IsReference = true, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize)]
    public SampleTree Parent { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class SampleClass
{
    public string A { get; set; }

    public int B { get; set; }

    public bool C { get; set; }
}
```

Program code (console app for simplicity):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tree = new SampleTree
    {
        Value = new SampleClass
        {
            A = "abc",
            B = 1,
            C = true
        },
        Parent = null
    };

    var treeChild = new SampleTree
    {
        Value = new SampleClass
        {
            A = "def",
            B = 2,
            C = false
        },
        Parent = tree
    };

    tree.Add("firstChild", treeChild);

    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };

    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree, serializerSettings);

    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleTree>(serialized, serializerSettings);

    var d = deserialized;
}
```

The result of serialization is just perfect: result string contains all the data I've putted to the tree before. However, deserialization of that string with the same serializer settings is incorrect: result object has no children at all. Maybe the main problem is attributes... What's the reason of behavior like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring Dictionary in Main function, I just added a property named Children of type Dictionary to SampleTree itself (and removed inheritance ofc).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you required.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, SampleTree> tree = new Dictionary<string, SampleTree>();
            var a = new SampleTree
            {
                Value = new SampleClass
                {
                    A = "abc",
                    B = 1,
                    C = true
                },
                Parent = null
            };

            var treeChild = new SampleTree
            {
                Value = new SampleClass
                {
                    A = "def",
                    B = 2,
                    C = false
                },
                Parent = a
            };

            tree.Add("parent", a);
            tree.Add("child", treeChild);

            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            };

            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree, serializerSettings);

            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SampleTree>>(serialized, serializerSettings);

            var d = deserialized;
        }
    }

    [JsonObject(IsReference = true, ItemReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize)]
    public class SampleTree
    {
        [JsonProperty(ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize)]
        public SampleClass Value { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(IsReference = true, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize)]
        public SampleTree Parent { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
    public class SampleClass
    {
        public string A { get; set; }

        public int B { get; set; }

        public bool C { get; set; }
    }

}
```

This worked flawlessly for me. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: That's close to my solution. Instead of declaring Dictionary<string, SampleTree> in Main function, I just added a property named Children of type Dictionary<string, SampleTree> to SampleTree itself (and removed inheritance ofc). But the main question is: how to get this work if I don't want to remove inheritance?